# Transposing columns into rows to create event log data set

Tags: python, pandas

could you please help me to transpose columns into rows to create event log series?

I want to create an event log data set out of the following columns.

My table looks like the following:

```
ID1     ID2      Event1             Event1_activity     Event2              Event2_activity     Event3              Event3_activity
10001A  6456    05.09.2019 12:32    Event1_Description  09.09.2019 12:40    Event2_Description  10.09.2019 12:40    Event3_Description
10001A  6456    05.09.2019 12:32    Event1_Description  09.09.2019 12:40    Event2_Description  10.09.2019 12:40    Event3_Description
20001B  8793    03.09.2019 09:45    Event1_Description  10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description  11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
20001B  9017    03.09.2019 09:49    Event1_Description  10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description  11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
20001B  5454    04.09.2019 12:42    Event1_Description  10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description  11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
```

According to **ID1** and **ID2**, I want to create a series of event logs based on the columns with respective events and activities.

Basically my event log table should look like the following:

```
ID          Event               Activity
6456-10001A 05.09.2019 12:32    Event1_Description
6456-10001A 09.09.2019 12:40    Event2_Description
6456-10001A 10.09.2019 12:40    Event3_Description
6456-10001A 05.09.2019 12:32    Event1_Description
6456-10001A 09.09.2019 12:40    Event2_Description
6456-10001A 10.09.2019 12:40    Event3_Description
8793-20001B 03.09.2019 09:45    Event1_Description
8793-20001B 10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description
8793-20001B 04.09.2019 09:45    Event3_Description
9017-20001B 03.09.2019 09:49    Event1_Description
9017-20001B 10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description
9017-20001B 04.09.2019 09:49    Event3_Description
5454-20001B 04.09.2019 12:42    Event1_Description
5454-20001B 10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description
5454-20001B 05.09.2019 12:42    Event3_Description
```

Any suggestions woud higly be appreciated!

Comment: amend question so data is as text not images

Comment: as @RobRaymond already mentioned, kindly share data, not images

Comment: Can you also share what you have done so far to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). Dynamic - more columns (>3) will still work.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""ID1     ID2      Event1             Event1_activity     Event2              Event2_activity     Event3              Event3_activity
10001A  6456    05.09.2019 12:32    Event1_Description  09.09.2019 12:40    Event2_Description  10.09.2019 12:40    Event3_Description
10001A  6456    05.09.2019 12:32    Event1_Description  09.09.2019 12:40    Event2_Description  10.09.2019 12:40    Event3_Description
20001B  8793    03.09.2019 09:45    Event1_Description  10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description  11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
20001B  9017    03.09.2019 09:49    Event1_Description  10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description  11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
20001B  5454    04.09.2019 12:42    Event1_Description  10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description  11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description"""
                            ), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

# pepare ID column as concatenation
df = df.assign(ID=lambda dfa: dfa["ID1"].astype(str)+"-"+dfa["ID2"].astype(str)).drop(columns=["ID1","ID2"])
# melt out both sets of columns for Event and Activity then merge
# NB reset_index() to ensure merge key works.  Plus only want ID on LHS dataframe
df2 = pd.merge(
    pd.melt(df, id_vars=["ID"], 
            value_vars=[c for c in df.columns if "Event" in c and "activity" not in c], 
            value_name="Event").drop(columns="variable").reset_index(),
    pd.melt(df, id_vars=["ID"], 
            value_vars=[c for c in df.columns if "activity" in c], 
            value_name="Activity").drop(columns=["variable","ID"]).reset_index(),

    on="index"
).drop(columns="index").sort_values(["ID","Event"])
```

### output

```
         ID            Event           Activity
10001A-6456 05.09.2019 12:32 Event1_Description
10001A-6456 05.09.2019 12:32 Event1_Description
10001A-6456 09.09.2019 12:40 Event2_Description
10001A-6456 09.09.2019 12:40 Event2_Description
10001A-6456 10.09.2019 12:40 Event3_Description
10001A-6456 10.09.2019 12:40 Event3_Description
20001B-5454 04.09.2019 12:42 Event1_Description
20001B-5454 10.09.2019 12:25 Event2_Description
20001B-5454 11.09.2019 12:25 Event3_Description
20001B-8793 03.09.2019 09:45 Event1_Description
20001B-8793 10.09.2019 12:25 Event2_Description
20001B-8793 11.09.2019 12:25 Event3_Description
20001B-9017 03.09.2019 09:49 Event1_Description
20001B-9017 10.09.2019 12:25 Event2_Description
20001B-9017 11.09.2019 12:25 Event3_Description
```

Comment: I am getting an empty DataFrame after applying it to my data sets. Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, Event, Activity]
Index: []

Comment: can you provide date from `df.head(5)` or at least `df.columns`.  what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Thank you @Rob Raymond. This helped to solve my problem. I figured out to add a keyword to column names and apply the melt function.

Answer (score 0):

df
[image]

You can create the new `ID` and then concatenate the dataframe subsets and sort by ID

```
df['ID'] = df['ID2'].astype(str) + '-' + df['ID1']
n_events = 3
pd.concat([df[['ID', f'Event{i}', f'Event{i}_activity']].rename(columns={f'Event{i}': 'Event', f'Event{i}_activity': 'Activity'}) 
           for i in range(1, n_events+1)]
         ).sort_values(by='ID').reset_index(drop=True)

        ID           Event             Activity
0   5454-20001B 04.09.2019 12:42    Event1_Description
1   5454-20001B 10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description
2   5454-20001B 11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
3   6456-10001A 05.09.2019 12:32    Event1_Description
4   6456-10001A 05.09.2019 12:32    Event1_Description
5   6456-10001A 09.09.2019 12:40    Event2_Description
6   6456-10001A 09.09.2019 12:40    Event2_Description
7   6456-10001A 10.09.2019 12:40    Event3_Description
8   6456-10001A 10.09.2019 12:40    Event3_Description
9   8793-20001B 03.09.2019 09:45    Event1_Description
10  8793-20001B 10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description
11  8793-20001B 11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
12  9017-20001B 03.09.2019 09:49    Event1_Description
13  9017-20001B 10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description
14  9017-20001B 11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
```

If you have to retain the original order of `ID`, then you have to do differently

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with create `ID` column and swapping columns names like `Event1_activity` to `activity_Event1`:

```
df['ID']  = df.pop("ID1").astype(str) + "-" + df.pop("ID2").astype(str))

df.columns = [f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}' if len(x) == 2 else f'{"".join(x)}' 
                for x in df.columns.str.split('_')]

df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
                      stubnames=['Event','activity_Event'],
                      i=['index','ID'],
                      j='tmp')
        .reset_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True))
print (df) 
            ID             Event      activity_Event
0   10001A-6456  05.09.2019 12:32  Event1_Description
1   10001A-6456  09.09.2019 12:40  Event2_Description
2   10001A-6456  10.09.2019 12:40  Event3_Description
3   10001A-6456  05.09.2019 12:32  Event1_Description
4   10001A-6456  09.09.2019 12:40  Event2_Description
5   10001A-6456  10.09.2019 12:40  Event3_Description
6   20001B-8793  03.09.2019 09:45  Event1_Description
7   20001B-8793  10.09.2019 12:25  Event2_Description
8   20001B-8793  11.09.2019 12:25  Event3_Description
9   20001B-9017  03.09.2019 09:49  Event1_Description
10  20001B-9017  10.09.2019 12:25  Event2_Description
11  20001B-9017  11.09.2019 12:25  Event3_Description
12  20001B-5454  04.09.2019 12:42  Event1_Description
13  20001B-5454  10.09.2019 12:25  Event2_Description
14  20001B-5454  11.09.2019 12:25  Event3_Description
```

Comment: Same for wide_to_long. Will "j" check for dtypes when you give any values? Even after converting timestamps to datetime, still getting an empty DataFrame.

Comment: @Firuz In my solution are very important columns names, function `wide_to_long` check columns with `Event1`, `activity_Event1` created from `Event1_activity`. In another words columns names and integer numbers 1, 2, 3...after them. Are real data columns names same? Or there is some difference? Because if no difference it should working well. If there is some  separator or some another pattern for columns names solution is necessary modify.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. My data has totally different column names. The above-mentioned example is a dummy one but I understood your solution. In case the name of columns is distinct which logic would be difficult to apply, for instance, let's assume that the names of columns are: 'ID', 'Date of delivery', ' Delivery Action', 'Shipment Date', 'Shipment status', and etc., how would 'wide_to_long' work?

Comment: @Firuz - What is `print (df.columns[:10])` ? Because here is necessary know pattern of `duplicated` columns names.

Answer (score 0):

The reshaping process could be abstracted by using the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

Your columns have a pattern - some end with numbers, while the rest end with `activity`. We can use a regular expression inside the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function to get your results :

```
# install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
 import janitor

(   # combine `ID1` and `ID2` into a single column
    df.assign(ID=df.ID2.astype(str).str.cat(df.ID1, sep="-"))
    .drop(columns=["ID1", "ID2"])
    .pivot_longer(
        index="ID",
        names_to=("Event", "Activity"),
        names_pattern=("\d$", "activity$"),
        sort_by_appearance=True,
    )
)

         ID               Event            Activity
0   6456-10001A     05.09.2019 12:32    Event1_Description
1   6456-10001A     09.09.2019 12:40    Event2_Description
2   6456-10001A     10.09.2019 12:40    Event3_Description
3   6456-10001A     05.09.2019 12:32    Event1_Description
4   6456-10001A     09.09.2019 12:40    Event2_Description
5   6456-10001A     10.09.2019 12:40    Event3_Description
6   8793-20001B     03.09.2019 09:45    Event1_Description
7   8793-20001B     10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description
8   8793-20001B     11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
9   9017-20001B     03.09.2019 09:49    Event1_Description
10  9017-20001B     10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description
11  9017-20001B     11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
12  5454-20001B     04.09.2019 12:42    Event1_Description
13  5454-20001B     10.09.2019 12:25    Event2_Description
14  5454-20001B     11.09.2019 12:25    Event3_Description
```

The `names_pattern` `("\d$", "activity$")` looks for the columns that end with number and `activity` and assigns them to the respective column names in `names_to` `("Event", "Activity")`